# Viable way to adopt ~20mm lens to Olympus Pen F/FT film camera?

Tags: film, 35mm, olympus, aps-c

I am interested in Olympus Pen F/FT film camera system (APS-C on 35mm film).

My largest concern is availability of wide angle lenses. I would like to have something like 28mm in 35mm equivalent, and the only (and the widest) available native option is 20mm/3.5 (28mm equivalent), which does not survive very well until this day due to haze/de-lamination on majority of ebay samples, despite it's relatively high cost.

I ether will have to disassemble and re-glue the lens - which is a challenge on it's own or adopt 3rd party or more modern Olympus lens.

Any suggestions on which path is most feasible to get 20mm or shorter lenses on Olympus PEN F/FT film camera? I would prefer to avoid full-frame 35mm lenses with huge flange focal distance, as it will be extremely bulky.

Comment: APS-C is  25.1 mm × 16.7 mm. Half-frame 35mm is 18 mm x 24 mm. Not a big difference, but a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have trouble avoiding full frame 35mm lenses. Olympus made the Olympus-Pen F Mount Adapter P, which allowed M42 threaded lenses, also known as the Pentax Screw Mount, to be mounted. Many manufacturers made M42 screw mount lenses, but they all are sized to make a full-size 35mm image circle.

[image: Olympus-Pen FMount Adapter P]

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be to get an (available in Ebay) EOS lens to PEN F mount adapter and then you could get a lot of manual lenses such as the ones from Samyang/Rokinon which sell several full frame wide angle rectilinear and fish eye lenses.

Best of luck!